# How to search all links in messenger conversation?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I'd like to find some usefull link I sent to a friend maybe year ago, but so far with no success. I tried `http, https, www, /, ...` but nothing lists that one, maybe it starts without protocol specified, I dunno. In whatsapp there is this functionality, msg has nothing. Or am I missing some step?

Comment: Have you tried export the message to JSON and do a regex checking on it?

Comment: Yeah maybe this should be at super user or whatnot meta. This is not technical, just whether am I blind or of there is some shortcut for wildcard search, which there probably isn't and its just hashed words in the history.